# Is there a method to make a method return in an inner method?

Tags: java, oop, methods, break

In object oriented language just like JAVA,how to make a method return by inner method?

For example,in some login scenario,we have to check the validation of input values,we just program like this:

```
...
if(checkValidate()){
   return;
}
dologin()
...
```

and the method checkValidate() has a return value of Boolean.

Is there a method to directly jump out the father method of the checkValidate(),like this:

```
...
checkValidate();
doLogin();
...
```

Just for curious,any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: It's called an 'exception'.

Comment: Why would you simply `return` instead of throwing an appropriate message?

Comment: What you call `inner method` it's really don't an inner method

Comment: It used to be called 'goto', but after the 'goto'-crusade it had to go undercover as 'exception'.

Comment: If there were a way to do exactly what you described without exceptions, I think it would make the source code hard to follow and/or debug

Comment: @JeroenVannevel I should have a toast or alert something,I just omit it to simplify my expression.

Comment: @Tom In that way I can change the methord name to checkValidateOrReturn() or something

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to achieve that is by throwing an exception which your father method does not catch. A custom exception, something like : InvalidLoginException